# Create a sql query that can handle multiple check box selections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a form with 3 check box dropdown lists enabling multiple selection from each control.

Lets say for talking sake its an accommodation table I am querying and the check box dropdown lists are 'AccommodationName', 'Company', and 'Nights'.

So potentially I could be passing in multiple values from each control and I want to return an aggregated query relevant to all data input.

How should I be going about this query?

Is the query going to have to be dynamic sql?

Please note, I am using sql server 2005.

Comment: when you select multiple values, does your application creates a comma deliminated list of them values ?

Comment: Dynamic sql, delimited data or xml are the usual approaches. sql2008 onwards you could use table value parameters. XML would be my choice to investigate. delimited data can work if you do it right, but it always makes me wince.

Comment: Another way would be to treat each checkbox as bits and 'bitwise or' them together (I.E. 1,2,4) and save them as single int field in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a split function inside you database,

### Definition Of Split Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split]
    (
      @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)
    ) 
 RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @xml XML
  SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'

  INSERT INTO @t(val)
  SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item
  FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r)
  RETURN
END
```

### Stored Procedure

Then you need to create a stored procedure which will build sql query dynamically and use this split function to handle multiple values passed as a comma deliminated list.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
    @AccommodationName  VARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @Company            VARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @Nights             VARCHAR(1000) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

 SET @SQL = N' SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 1 = 1 '
            + CASE WHEN @AccommodationName IS NOT NULL 
                THEN N' AND AccommodationName IN (SELECT Val FROM dbo.split(@AccommodationName )) '
                    ELSE N'' END
            + CASE WHEN @Company IS NOT NULL 
                THEN N' AND Company IN (SELECT Val FROM dbo.split(@Company)) '
                    ELSE N'' END
            + CASE WHEN @Nights IS NOT NULL 
                THEN N' AND Nights IN (SELECT Val FROM dbo.split(@Nights)) '
                    ELSE N'' END

  EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
                       ,N'@AccommodationName VARCHAR(1000), @Company VARCHAR(1000), @Nights VARCHAR(1000)'
                       ,@AccommodationName 
                       ,@Company 
                       ,@Nights 
END
```