# Pass multiple selected items in Listbox to stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

There are two listboxes. [lstid and lstselected]. When user selects one or multiple ID in [lstid] and click move right. The selected items will be in [lstselected]

I am trying to pass the multiple value from [lstselected] to stored procedure and bind the data to [gridview] but received the following error.

[startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.]

Appreciate that anyone can help on this?

**ASP**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="reimbursementlb.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Reimbursenment Report</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 153px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form2" runat="server">
<div>
 <table align=center>
<tr>
<td align="center" class="auto-style1" >
    <h4>Reimbursement ID </h4>
</td>
<td>
    <h4></h4>
    </td>
<td>
    <h4>
<b>Selected ID</b></h4>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="auto-style1">
<asp:ListBox ID="lstid" runat="server"  Height="175px" Width="131px" SelectionMode="Multiple" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="ID" DataValueField="ID">
</asp:ListBox>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CLMSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ID] FROM [PaymentConsoleClosing] ORDER BY [ID] DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</td>
<td>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnMoveRight" runat="server" Text=">" Width="45px" onclick="btnMoveRight_Click" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnMoveLeft" runat="server" Text="<" Width="45px" onclick="btnMoveLeft_Click" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>
<asp:ListBox ID="lstSelected" runat="server" Height="175px" Width="120px"  SelectionMode="Multiple" style="margin-left: 0px">

</asp:ListBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<asp:Label ID="lbltxt" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit"
        onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px">
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private arraylist1 As New ArrayList()
    Private arraylist2 As New ArrayList()

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
    Protected Sub btnMoveRight_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnMoveRight.Click
        lbltxt.Visible = False
        If lstid.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To lstid.Items.Count - 1
                If lstid.Items(i).Selected Then
                    If Not arraylist1.Contains(lstid.Items(i)) Then
                        arraylist1.Add(lstid.Items(i))
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            For i As Integer = 0 To arraylist1.Count - 1
                If Not lstSelected.Items.Contains(DirectCast(arraylist1(i), ListItem)) Then
                    lstSelected.Items.Add(DirectCast(arraylist1(i), ListItem))
                End If
                lstid.Items.Remove(DirectCast(arraylist1(i), ListItem))
            Next
            lstSelected.SelectedIndex = -1
        Else
            lbltxt.Visible = True
            lbltxt.Text = "Please select at least one in lstid to move"
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnMoveLeft_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        lbltxt.Visible = False
        If lstSelected.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To lstSelected.Items.Count - 1
                If lstSelected.Items(i).Selected Then
                    If Not arraylist2.Contains(lstSelected.Items(i)) Then
                        arraylist2.Add(lstSelected.Items(i))
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            For i As Integer = 0 To arraylist2.Count - 1
                If Not lstid.Items.Contains(DirectCast(arraylist2(i), ListItem)) Then
                    lstid.Items.Add(DirectCast(arraylist2(i), ListItem))
                End If
                lstSelected.Items.Remove(DirectCast(arraylist2(i), ListItem))
            Next
            lstid.SelectedIndex = -1
        Else
            lbltxt.Visible = True
            lbltxt.Text = "Please select at least one in lstSelected to move"
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CLMSConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        Dim strID As String = ""
        For Each li As ListItem In lstSelected.Items()
            If li.Selected Then
                strID = (strID + ("," + li.Value))
            End If
        Next
        strID = strID.Substring(1)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.ConsoleClosingListSearch"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ConsoleClosingID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = strID
        cmd.Connection = con
        Try
            con.Open()
            GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found"
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            GridView1.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
SELECT *
FROM PaymentTransaction_ConsoleClosing
WHERE
    PaymentTransaction_ConsoleClosing.PaymentConsoleClosingID IN (@ConsoleClosingID
```

Comment: Depends on which **version** of SQL Server you're using. If you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer, use the *table-valued parameter* feature to pass a "table of data" from your VB.NET code to a SQL Server stored procedure. See e.g. [C# and Table Valued Parameter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39161/C-and-Table-Value-Parameters) on how to do this (works just as fine in VB.NET, too)

Comment: Which line produce an error?

Comment: This line produce error [strID = strID.Substring(1)].I am using sql server 2005

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a sql query that can handle multiple check box selections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762191/create-a-sql-query-that-can-handle-multiple-check-box-selections)

Answer (score 0):

Well judging by your comment, your immediate error - `startIndex cannot be larger than length of string` is because you are trying to substring a string that isn't as long as you expect it to be.

You say it occurs on this line:

```
strID = strID.Substring(1)
```

What this will do is return a string that starts from the first index (second character) all the way to the end of the string. If `strID` isn't at least two characters long, you'll get an error.

Make sure your `strID` string is getting populated correctly and possibly add a condition before the Substring() call to make sure the string is long enough.